# Any suggestion on package for drawing 'random intervals' charts?

Tags: python, charts

I need to create a chart with the system load over a period of time. The main issue is that the data extraction is happening at random intervals so I need to be able to specify the X axis time position for the value. Any suggestion on a package/module with such functionality ?

Sample Data:

```
data = { '10:20' : 5, '10:28' : 8, '10:30' : 1 }
```

Comment: What kind of interface are you talking about? PyQt4? GTK? Generating images? Web?

Comment: Right now exporting to a PNG would be sufficient, I will probably integrated it on a GTK app later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem; any graphing library will let you specify `x` coordinates for the points that you plot. Try e.g. [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have just tried simpler chart plotting libraries, most didn't allow me to set X positions, only X labels. Also please note that on my case  I need to provide time related positions. I could conver h:m:s to total seconds for the position, but on that case I would need to set X axis labeling per the corresponding time value.

Comment: I seems "matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date" will do what I need, now I just need to learn to use matplotlib in general.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

biggles is a decent Python graphing library. You can use SciPy to interpolate if you need to fill in empty spots on your graph.